# How to remove the last two characters from multiple folders, but only where they contain specific letters

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I have multiple folders named *cv, which need to be renamed to just *. (** = variable number).

However, the folders which do not contain cv should not be renamed.

Comment: Are you doing this in PowerShell or cmd since you picked both tags? Is there anything else you have tried? I don't see any looping or filtering?

Comment: I don't mind if it's in cmd or PowerShell, as long as it works. I have very basic knowledge of cmd and PowerShell so no, that's all I've tried. Why am I getting down votes? I can't see an answer anywhere else

Comment: Were not here to write the code for you, we're happy to assist with issues but it would help if you made a real attempt at coding something and let us know where you run into trouble.  To get you started I'll point you in the direction of [Get-ChildItem](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176841.aspx)(especially look at the `-Filter` parameter) and then the [Rename-Item](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176940.aspx) cmdlet. also  [Pipeline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/fundamental/understanding-the-windows-powershell-pipeline)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achived the desired result using the following code in powershell:

```
Get-ChildItem *cv | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -Replace 'cv','1' }
```